# Слежение за изменением Transform Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно отследить, кто изменяет значения Transform у какого - нибудь объекта на сцене? В интернете есть ответы, но там они в основном состоят в том, чтобы оборачивать Transform еще в начале проекта в свойства, которые можно логировать. Но проект уже есть и большой,  есть ли другой способ узнать, кто меняет значения моего Transform?

Comment: Никак, делай обертку

Answer (score 2):

На удивление это очень просто!

Достаточно иcпользовать расширения (*Extensions*) для классов и включить смекалку!

Ваши действия будут состоять из трёх этапов:

1. Создать скрипт *TransformHelperLog* и повесить на объект за которым хотите следить. (в нём можно ничего не писать)
2. Создать скрипт под именем **TransformExtensions** (чуть ниже будет представлен его код)
3. Во всём вашем проекте заменить обращение к трансформу `.transform => .GetTransform()` используя комбинацию клавиш *(ctrl + shift + F)*

Скрипт **TransformExtensions**  выглядит так:

```
 public static class TransformExtensions {
     public static Transform GetTransform(this global::UnityEngine.Transform transform) {
        if(transform.GetComponent<TransformHelperLog>() != null) {
            Debug.Log("It's moving! " + transform.name);
        }
        return transform;
     }
 }
```

Пример изменённого обращения гдето в разных скриптах:

```
void Update () {
   //someObject.transform.position += Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime; //было
   someObject.GetTransform().position += Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime; //стало      
}
```

Далее по логам сможете найти, кто меняет Transform. Как только найдёте кто меняет ваш трансформ, можете вернуть обращение к трансформу в изначальный вариант.